# Re-Positioning Scroll to Top Button when Footer appears (So it never overlaps)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a "click to scroll up" button implemented on my website, the button itself works fine, but my only issue is that when it reaches the footer, it overlaps it. I would like the button to not overlap the item, and stop at the top of the footer at a set distance.

Here is my current button CSS:

```
.back-to-top {
position: fixed;
right: 25px;
display: none;
z-index: 99;    
}
```

And here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('#back-to-top').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 400);
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Here it is in a codepen: https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/ZEbyNXe

*I could of course adjust the padding/margin so that it avoids the footer altogether, but this is not a solution I want as if I were to ever extend the footer my button would be too far up the page.*

As you can see, the scroll up button overlaps the footer. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT: Footer CSS**

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;     
  height: 4rem;   /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 4rem; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color:#292929;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff; 
  padding-right: 2rem;
  bottom: 0;      
}
```

Comment: That would probably be the case for an Intersection observer.

Comment: Actually, if you always know the height of the footer, you can just tie it into a scroll event. Let me see if I can work something without an IO. :)

Comment: Thanks :) My footer height stays constant, but would be nice to change footer height without having to re-edit the javascript, so maybe it could be worked out automatically. see my edited post with footer css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. Let me know! [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jrhager84/pen/QWjgXvq)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// Should cache elements here for continuous access
const footer = $(".footer");
const scrollBtn = $("#back-to-top"); 
const padding = 25; // So you can change this is one value
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  
  // Where we're gonna set the button's height
  var distanceFromBottom = Math.floor($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop() - $(window).height());
  // Check to see if we're within the footer range
  if ( distanceFromBottom <= footer.height() ) {
    console.log(distanceFromBottom);
    scrollBtn.css("bottom", (footer.height() - distanceFromBottom) + padding);
   } else {
    scrollBtn.css("bottom", padding);
   }
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
   } else {
    $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
   }
  });
  // scroll body to 0px on click
  $('#back-to-top').click(function () {
   $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
   }, 400);
   return false;
  });
});
```

```css
html {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
}


body {
 background-color: #3498db;
 color: #ecf0f1;
}

.back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    display: none;
   z-index: 99;
}

.footer {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;     
 height: 4rem;   /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
 line-height: 4rem; /* Vertically center the text there */
 background-color:#292929;
 text-align: right;
 color: #fff; 
 padding-right: 2rem;
 bottom: 0;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
  <div class="col-8 my-5">
   <p class="h5">Hello!</p>
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/900x300" class="img-fluid rounded mb-3" alt="">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/900x300" class="img-fluid rounded mb-3" alt="">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/900x300" class="img-fluid rounded mb-3" alt="">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/900x300" class="img-fluid rounded alt="">   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg back-to-top" role="button"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                  <footer class="footer">Copyright </footer>
```

Comment: For some reason the width is messed up in the snippet. Check the CodePen for the actual result. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is precisely what I was looking for.